# Translate from LINQ query syntax to method syntax

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following join:

```
var simpleJoin = from b in books
                 join p in publishers on b.PublisherName equals p.Name
                 where p.Id == 1
                 select b;
```

What is the equivalent using the method syntax? I'm getting tripped up by the filter:

```
simpleJoin = books.Join(publishers, p => p.PublisherName, b => b.Name, (b, p) => b).Where(*can't access publishers here*)
```

Can I not use `books` as my source collection? I'm wondering how we could manage filtering if we have multiple joins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to include both **b** and **p** in the `resultSelector`.  For example, using an anonymous-typed object:

```
simpleJoin = books.Join(publishers, p => p.PublisherName, b => b.Name, 
        (b, p) => new { b = b, p = p })
    .Where(result => result.p.Id == 1)
    .Select(result => result.b);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can filter the `publishers` list prior to joining it to `books`:

```
var simpleJoin = books.Join(publishers.Where(p => p.Id == 1),
                             b => b.PublisherName, p => p.Name, (b, p) => b);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just as example - you can also make it without join clause:

```
books.Where(b => publishers.Exists(p => p.Name == b.PublisherName && p.Id == 1));
```